# R trouble reading my files with read.csv

Tags: r, csv, datareader

I'm currently trying to read two .csv files, edit the data, and then write it into a new .csv.

here the code :

```
data <- read.csv("file.csv"), fill=TRUE, header=TRUE, row.names=NULL, stringAsFactors=FALSE, sep=",", quote="")
write.csv(data, file="out.csv")
```

Here's the problem :
Everything is fine with the first file (20 columns, 572 observations)

However, the other file has 163 columns and 1578 lines but when I read it with read.csv, R displays "2301 observations of 163 variables".

I tried to write this dataframe into a new csv file, and it is a total mess :

1. the rows have not been written entirely, the last values are written on a new row
2. there is a new column with integers from 1 to 2301
3. some data which is supposed to be in file$n is written in file$(n-1) or file$(n-2)

I'm a newbie, and I must admit I'm kind of lost : any help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks

Clément

Comment: Difficult to say without the file.

Comment: 2. The new column is the row names, use `row.names=FALSE` in the `write.csv` call.

Comment: Unfortunately the file is confidential... I cannot upload it without modifying it.

However : I deleted a few columns, and now R reads it propely : 1578 lines and the new number of columns.

Is there a maximum number of columns read.csv can actually read?

Comment: You know what we want...your code that produced the problem!

Comment: How do you know the csv has 1578 lines? Is that just 1578 rows in your spreadsheet, or a line-count in an editor or something? Some spreadsheets write line-breaks and that might mess up the way R reads it back in. Find out where the R input starts to go wrong and match that up with the CSV.

Comment: Basically, it's 1578 in the spreadsheet. I wil perform a line count on the raw file.

Comment: Does `data[1,1:10]` look okay? Does `data[10,1:10]` look okay? Does `data[2301,1:10]` look okay? Repeat until first problem row found, find corresponding line in CSV file, figure out problem.

Comment: You should avoid blaming the function: if your title read "Trouble reading *MY* file with "read.csv" it'd be more accurate.

Comment: Just a wild guess: in one column you have character strings with apostrophes or quotes.

Comment: Thank you plannapus, it seems you found the nature of the problem.

Thank you all for your help.